# Using "Community wiki" to avoid being downvoted?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Is what [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4073753/ahosan-karim-asik?tab=activity&sort=posts) is doing a valid and appropriate use of the ability to mark an answer as "Community Wiki"?

The answers I read are not *stellar*, or otherwise useful in a broad sense. (See [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) for a short overview.) I believe the OP is just attempting to avoid downvotes.

Comment: Well, they're also not *gaining* any reputation from their upvotes and accepts. Kind of a silly thing to do.

Comment: Is it possible for a user to get answer-banned for having lots of CW answers deleted?

Comment: @Andrew I don't believe the CW flag has any affect on it. Besides, they have just as many upvoted answers as downvoted answers.

Comment: I hate answers like this. I've looked at about 10 and each are just "Try this:  /* code */" without any explanation whatsoever.

Comment: " I believe the OP is just attempting to avoid down votes". Why have you come to this conclusion regarding their motivation? They could be confused about CW or simply trying to encourage improvements by others.

Comment: @MartinSmith: from the blog post mentioned below by Jeremy Banks: "Community wiki is for that rare gem of a post that needs true community collaboration." If the OP *misunderstood* the purpose of the "Make CW" button, then would it not be appropriate to have a moderator undo this for all of his posts?

Comment: I have recently made a community wiki for just this reason... I have a hard time writing good answers... did not realize i would get no rep.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't personally have a problem with it. In exchange for avoiding downvotes, they're also giving up the possibility of receiving upvotes for those answers.

If the answers are bad, users can still downvote them so they sink to the bottom, and flag/delete if appropriate.

Comment: One problem is that they don't seem to be using CW "correctly" so it's going to confuse others on what they are meant for.

Comment: I guess I'm still not quite sure what community wikis are *for*. Yes, they can be edited by low-rep users. Somehow I don't think that would lead to a greater quality -- quite the reverse. Is this only a historical remnant of the original SO? Can't the entire concept get ditched?

Comment: @Jongware Related: [blog: The Future of Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)

Comment: There are some who like to curate particular tags and like to try and drive down the percentage of unanswered questions. In some cases, questions will have no actual answer, but will be answered in the comments. In some cases, these questions sit for a long time in this state.  In those cases, I have seen some tag "curators" collect the relevant part of the comments into an answer, but mark the answer as community wiki, since they (reasonably) feel that they do not deserve credit for the answer. This seems a valid use of community wiki (to me) although I don't see it covered in the blog.

Comment: I've seen it used with answers that are essentially ads for the respondent's product. Knowing that the response will be perceived as commercial in nature, the answerer classifies his/her response as CM to avoid downvotes.