# Is it legitimate to mark (almost) all of your answers as "community wiki"?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I am wondering if it is legitimate for a user to provide all (or almost all) of their answers as "community wiki"?

Here's one user I found - [DeepDave-MT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15969115/deepdave-mt) who has been marking almost all of their answers as "community wiki".

To be honest, I didn't know about the community wiki thing until today, but my understanding is that one should mark their answer as "community wiki" if they expect other users to edit that answer to better it and for [other reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343086/why-would-you-mark-an-answer-as-community-wiki).

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Tangentially, FYI, those "-MT" accounts belong to Microsoft support staff.

Comment: @yivi - Thanks. I don't know hence asking :). Does it lessen the value of "community wiki" if every answer is marked such. Regarding "-MT", yes you are correct. My guess is that Microsoft outsourced Stack Overflow support to some company here in India and all users with "-MT" in their name are employees of that company.

Comment: But why would anything be "lessened"? I'm sorry, but I just don't get what could possibly be wrong about any user doing it, what harm could it cause the site, what avenue for abuse would present, etc.

Comment: That is what I am trying to understand. If there are no side effects, then I guess it is ok for a user to mark all of their answers as community wiki.

Comment: One potential use (not likely in this case) is to [avoid negative reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277400/using-community-wiki-to-avoid-being-downvoted) from downvotes. It seems also possible that one might try to use this to avoid the automated answer ban, but hopefully SO has thought of that.

Comment: "*my understanding is that one should mark their answer as "community wiki" if they expect other users to edit that answer to better it*" why wouldn't this apply? If a user decides they want to contribute wiki answers, what exactly is the issue?

Comment: Please see this (comment): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71515236/can-you-import-a-tensorflow-model-written-in-python-into-an-microsoft-azure-envi/71567399#71567399 as an example.

Comment: And as you can read in that comment (_"Sorry, but making your answers community wiki doesn't shield them from having to be original content. Stack Overflow is not meant to be a copy of the Microsoft documentation._") the deletion had nothing to do with the answer being a community wiki. Without any further details on why one could expect this behavior to be wrong, it's difficult to answer anything else than "it's not wrong".

Comment: I hope Microsoft will provide the right incentives for the contractor. The *number* of answered questions wouldn't be. A suggested edit should have been submitted for such a terrible question. Or not answered at all. Some kind of question score could be applied and answering only allowed above a certain threshold. Awards for ***finding duplicates*** over answering the same questions over and over could benefit all (e.g., it is a shortcut for the contractor when the duplicate is known by the contractor).

Comment: Stack Overflow needs to be a lot simpler than you are making it like this. You can do a search "community wiki" in the help center and that will point you to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) explaining the privilege to create them. Does that page say anything about rules regarding how many you are allowed to create? No. So assume there is no such limit until you learn otherwise, then blame it on incomplete documentation. I am sure your creative mind can come up with hundreds of corner cases, don't do it to yourself.

Comment: Here is another user, *[AnsumanBal-MT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15969299/ansumanbal-mt?tab=answers)*, with a much better answers structure (but [with (unreadable) screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71220123) of text). It is a *much* better answer (only linking to Microsoft document and only quoting the relevant part). The problem in the question is actually reproduced. This is what we want to see!. [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69310603) of text as (unreadable) screenshots. What is an acceptable and *effective* canned comment for it?

Comment: [The canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/) only mentions questions, not answers.

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri: Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15969299/ansumanbal-mt?tab=answers&sort=newest&page=12) with *excellent* answers (409 so far).

Comment: But also [with gross overformatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71153256) (***all*** text in bold and/or italics). And program output as screenshots.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, it's perfectly legitimate.

Comment: I see what you did there :)