# Why can't I uncheck the community wiki option without moderator assistance?

Tags: support, community-wiki

When I click on community wiki check, it warns me that the community wiki option cannot be unchecked without the assistance of the moderators. Why is this rule there?

Comment: Because then you could CW all your answers, wait to see how they do, [leave the downvoted ones as CW](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277400/3270037), and remove the CW from the ones that do well, profit.

Comment: Once you have transferred ownership of the question, it is no longer your decision to transfer it back. I don't know if a moderator is likely to deny this request.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny My stance (in my capacity as a mod on another SE site) on it is *I would be very, very reluctant to reverse the community wiki status of any post, specially once it got edited by more users then just the original OP.*